# Computing mixed derivatives in MATLAB using syms and diff

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

I'm using MATLAB 2012b.
I want to get d²/dxdy of a simple function:

```
f(x,y) = (x-1)² + 2y²
```

The documentation states that I can use `syms` and `diff` as in the following example:

```
> syms x y
> diff(x*sin(x*y), x, y)
ans =
    2*x*cos(x*y) - x^2*y*sin(x*y)
```

But doing the same I got the wrong answer:

```
> syms x y
> f = (x-1)^2 + 2*y^2;
> diff(f,x,y)
ans = 
    4*y
```

The answer is right if I use `diff` like this:

```
diff(diff(f,x),y)
```

Well, it's not a problem for me to use it this way, but nevertheless why is the first variant not working? Is it a version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual documentation from R2010a:

> diff(expr) differentiates a symbolic expression expr with respect to its free variable as determined by symvar.
>
> diff(expr, v) and diff(expr, sym('v')) differentiate expr with respect to v.
>
> diff(expr, n) differentiates expr n times. n is a positive integer.
>
> diff(expr, v, n) and diff(expr, n, v) differentiate expr with respect to v n times.

So, the command `diff(f,x,y)` is the last case. It would be equal to differentiating `f` w.r.t. `x`, `y` times, or w.r.t `y`, `x` times.

For some reason I don't quite understand, you don't get a warning or error, but one of the `syms` variables gets interpreted as `n = 1`, and then the differentiation is carried out. In this case, what `diff` seems to do is basically `diff(f, y, 1)`.

In any case, it seems that the behavior changed from version to version, because in the documentation you link to (R2016b), there is an additional case:

> diff(F,var1,...,varN) differentiates F with respect to the variables var1,...,varN

So I suspect you're running into a version issue.

If you want to differentiate twice, both w.r.t `x` and `y`, your second attempt is indeed the correct and most portable way to do that:

```
diff( diff(f,x), y )
```

or equivalently

```
diff( diff(f,y), x )
```

**NB**
I checked the R2010a code for `symbolic/symbolic/@sym/diff.m` and indeed, `n` is defaulted to `1` and only changed if one of the input variables is a `double`, and the variable to differentiate over is set equal to the last `syms` variable in the argument list. The multiple `syms` variable call is not supported, nor detected and error-trapped.

Answer (score 0):

Syms is only creating symbolic variables.

The first code you execute is only a single derivative. The second code you provided differentiates two times. So I think you forgot to differentiate a second time in the first piece of code you provided.

I am also wondering what answer you expect? If you want 4*y as answer, than you should use

```
diff(f,y)
```

and not

```
diff(f,x,y)
```

Performing the second derivative is giving me zero?

```
diff(diff(f,x),y)
```

If you want 4 as answer than you have to do following:

```
diff(diff(f,y),y)
```

Comment: Yes, zero is the right answer. And it is the second mixed derivative. The problem is that in matlab documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) syntax like diff(x*sin(x*y), x, y) should also give the second mixed derivative, but on my computer it doesn't.